# how get value of array in php code

Tags: php

i want get value of array in php , but it don't ...
my print_r($_POST) is :

```html
Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            [site_core_selection] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                )

            [domain] => Array
                (
                    [0] => com
                )

            [hidden_premier] => 
            [shoping_hidden] => 
            [submit] => ØªØ§Ø¦ÛŒØ¯ Ø³ÙØ§Ø±Ø´
            [formId] => 3
        )

)
```

i want get value of domain[0] , please help me ??

Comment: try $_POST['form']['domain'][0]

Comment: try $_POST['form']['domain'][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **php** is very simple, try this code:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST["form"]["domain"][0];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out this

```
<?php
echo $_POST['form']['domain'][0];
?>
```